# Breakpoint does not trigger. "Breakpoint set but not yet bound". Docker, NodeJS, VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I can not debug my TypeScript files properly. The problem is that breakpoints in other files then `index.ts` do not get triggered. VSCode says "Breakpoint set but not yet bound" on them.

**How can I get all breakpoints to work?**

Backend/index.ts

```
import { myCoolFunctionFromOtherFile } from "helpers/file2.ts";
// ...

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    console.log("this breakpoint triggers successfully"); // <-- breakpoint triggers
    myCoolFunctionFromOtherFile();
});
```

Backend/helpers/file2.ts

```
export const myCoolFunctionFromOtherFile = () => {
    console.log("This breakpoint will not be triggered"); // <-- Breakpoint will not break. VSCode says "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".
};
```

Backend/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9229

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "debug"]
```

Backend/package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "ts-node-dev --poll --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --respawn index.ts", // I also tried nodemon, but could not get either to work
```

launch.json

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Docker",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Backend",
            "remoteRoot": "/app",
            "sourceMaps": true,

        }
    ]
```

fyi: When trying to debug locally without docker (run the scripts directly on my machine), then debugging works correctly. So I think it's some configuration error.

**Edit 1**

Add tsconfig.json

Enable inlineSourceMap and inlineSources

Also enable sourceMaps in launch.json

Backend/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "rootDir": "source",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true
    },
    "include": ["source"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable source maps in your `tsconfig` and make sure your launch config `launch.json` has the value `"sourceMaps" : true`

Your `tsconfig` should look something like this

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "preserveWhitespaces": "off",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",

    "sourceMaps": true, // add this instead it will generate .map files which you need to tell your launch.json where they are 
    // "inlineSourceMap": true, // remove this
    // "inlineSources": true, // remove this too
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

and your `launch.json`

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Docker",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Backend",
            "remoteRoot": "/app",
            "sourceMaps": true // set to enable sourcemaps
            // and if you have any webpack or anything else setup, map them properly with these settings 
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "meteor://app/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*",
                "webpack://?:*/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
            },
        }
    ]
```

Read more about how to debug Typescript code [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging)

Comment: I enabled sourcemaps as you told, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work properly. At least I can now get a breakpoint to trigger in file2.ts, but the breakpoint somehow jumps to another position.

Comment: Ah thats mainly due to inline sourcemaps, i updated the answer